# How to fix the distutils.errors.LinkError when configuring PyStan on Windows

Tags: python, c++, gcc, distutils, pystan

I am configuring PyStan on Windows and getting an error in the execution of the pystan.StanModel step.
Configure exactly according to the official documentation: https://pystan2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/windows.html#installing-c-compiler.

```
             active environment : None
       user config file : C:\Users\pytest\.condarc
       populated config files : C:\Users\pytest\.condarc
          conda version : 4.13.0
    conda-build version : not installed
         python version : 3.9.12.final.0
       virtual packages : __win=0=0
                          __archspec=1=x86_64
       base environment : C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3  (writable)
       conda av data dir : C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\etc\conda
       conda av metadata url : None
           channel URLs : http://mirrors.aliyun.com/anaconda/pkgs/main/win-64
                          http://mirrors.aliyun.com/anaconda/pkgs/main/noarch
                          http://mirrors.aliyun.com/anaconda/pkgs/r/win-64
                          http://mirrors.aliyun.com/anaconda/pkgs/r/noarch
                          http://mirrors.aliyun.com/anaconda/pkgs/msys2/win-64
                          http://mirrors.aliyun.com/anaconda/pkgs/msys2/noarch
          package cache : C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\pkgs
                          C:\Users\pytest\.conda\pkgs
                          C:\Users\pytest\AppData\Local\conda\conda\pkgs
       envs directories : C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs
                          C:\Users\pytest\.conda\envs
                          C:\Users\pytest\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs
               platform : win-64
             user-agent : conda/4.13.0 requests/2.28.0 CPython/3.9.12 Windows/10 Windows/10.0.15063
          administrator : True
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False
```

Error details are printed with verbose=True

The error message is

```
model = pystan.StanModel(verbose=True,model_code=model_code)
INFO:pystan:COMPILING THE C++ CODE FOR MODEL anon_model_5944b02c79788fa0db5b3a93728ca2bf NOW.
INFO:pystan:OS: win32, Python: 3.7.13 (default, Mar 28 2022, 08:03:21) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)], Cython 0.29.30
Compiling C:\Users\pytest\AppData\Local\Temp\pystan_wodq41el\stanfit4anon_model_5944b02c79788fa0db5b3a93728ca2bf_4906440559444162650.pyx because it changed.
[1/1] Cythonizing C:\Users\pytest\AppData\Local\Temp\pystan_wodq41el\stanfit4anon_model_5944b02c79788fa0db5b3a93728ca2bf_4906440559444162650.pyx
building 'stanfit4anon_model_5944b02c79788fa0db5b3a93728ca2bf_4906440559444162650' extension
gcc -mdll -O -Wall -DMS_WIN64 -DBOOST_RESULT_OF_USE_TR1 -DBOOST_NO_DECLTYPE -DBOOST_DISABLE_ASSERTS -IC:\Users\pytest\AppData\Local\Temp\pystan_wodq41el -IC:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\pythonProject\lib\site-packages\pystan -IC:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\pythonProject\lib\site-packages\pystan\stan\src -IC:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\pythonProject\lib\site-packages\pystan\stan\lib\stan_math -IC:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\pythonProject\lib\site-packages\pystan\stan\lib\stan_math\lib\eigen_3.3.3 -IC:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\pythonProject\lib\site-packages\pystan\stan\lib\stan_math\lib\boost_1.69.0 -IC:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\pythonProject\lib\site-packages\pystan\stan\lib\stan_math\lib\sundials_4.1.0\include -IC:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\pythonProject\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -IC:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\pythonProject\include -IC:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\pythonProject\Include -c C:\Users\pytest\AppData\Local\Temp\pystan_wodq41el\stanfit4anon_model_5944b02c79788fa0db5b3a93728ca2bf_4906440559444162650.cpp -o c:\users\pytest\appdata\local\temp\pystan_wodq41el\stanfit4anon_model_5944b02c79788fa0db5b3a93728ca2bf_4906440559444162650.o -O2 -ftemplate-depth-256 -Wno-unused-function -Wno-uninitialized -std=c++1y -D_hypot=hypot -pthread -fexceptions
In file included from C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\pythonProject\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include/numpy/ndarraytypes.h:1969:0,
                 from C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\pythonProject\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h:12,
                 from C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\pythonProject\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include/numpy/arrayobject.h:4,
                 from C:\Users\pytest\AppData\Local\Temp\pystan_wodq41el\stanfit4anon_model_5944b02c79788fa0db5b3a93728ca2bf_4906440559444162650.cpp:791:
C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\pythonProject\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include/numpy/npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h:15:77: note: #pragma message: C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\pythonProject\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include/numpy/npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h(14) : Warning Msg: Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it with #define NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION
                          "#define NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION")
                                                                             ^
In file included from C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\pythonProject\lib\site-packages\pystan\stan\lib\stan_math/stan/math/prim/mat/prob/poisson_log_glm_log.hpp:5:0,
                 from C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\pythonProject\lib\site-packages\pystan\stan\lib\stan_math/stan/math/prim/mat.hpp:336,
                 from C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\pythonProject\lib\site-packages\pystan\stan\src/stan/io/dump.hpp:6,
                 from C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\pythonProject\lib\site-packages\pystan/py_var_context.hpp:12,
                 from C:\Users\pytest\AppData\Local\Temp\pystan_wodq41el\stanfit4anon_model_5944b02c79788fa0db5b3a93728ca2bf_4906440559444162650.cpp:800:
C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\pythonProject\lib\site-packages\pystan\stan\lib\stan_math/stan/math/prim/mat/prob/poisson_log_glm_lpmf.hpp: In function 'typename stan::return_type<T_x, T_alpha, T_beta>::type stan::math::poisson_log_glm_lpmf(const T_y&, const T_x&, const T_alpha&, const T_beta&)':
C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\pythonProject\lib\site-packages\pystan\stan\lib\stan_math/stan/math/prim/mat/prob/poisson_log_glm_lpmf.hpp:64:59: warning: typedef 'T_alpha_val' locally defined but not used [-Wunused-local-typedefs]
       typename partials_return_type<T_alpha>::type>::type T_alpha_val;
                                                           ^
In file included from C:\Users\pytest\AppData\Local\Temp\pystan_wodq41el\stanfit4anon_model_5944b02c79788fa0db5b3a93728ca2bf_4906440559444162650.cpp:801:0:
C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\pythonProject\lib\site-packages\pystan/stan_fit.hpp: In function 'int pystan::{anonymous}::command(pystan::StanArgs&, Model&, pystan::StanHolder&, const std::vector<long long unsigned int>&, const std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >&, RNG_t&)':
C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\pythonProject\lib\site-packages\pystan/stan_fit.hpp:841:12: warning: 'template<class> class std::auto_ptr' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
       std::auto_ptr<stan::io::var_context> init_context_ptr;
            ^
In file included from C:/ProgramData/Miniconda3/envs/pythonProject/Library/mingw-w64/include/c++/5.3.0/memory:81:0,
                 from C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\pythonProject\lib\site-packages\pystan\stan\lib\stan_math\lib\boost_1.69.0/boost/config/no_tr1/memory.hpp:21,
                 from C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\pythonProject\lib\site-packages\pystan\stan\lib\stan_math\lib\boost_1.69.0/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:23,
                 from C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\pythonProject\lib\site-packages\pystan\stan\lib\stan_math\lib\boost_1.69.0/boost/shared_ptr.hpp:17,
                 from C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\pythonProject\lib\site-packages\pystan\stan\lib\stan_math/stan/math/prim/mat/fun/LDLT_factor.hpp:7,
                 from C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\pythonProject\lib\site-packages\pystan\stan\lib\stan_math/stan/math/prim/mat/err/check_ldlt_factor.hpp:6,
                 from C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\pythonProject\lib\site-packages\pystan\stan\lib\stan_math/stan/math/prim/mat.hpp:34,
                 from C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\pythonProject\lib\site-packages\pystan\stan\src/stan/io/dump.hpp:6,
                 from C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\pythonProject\lib\site-packages\pystan/py_var_context.hpp:12,
                 from C:\Users\pytest\AppData\Local\Temp\pystan_wodq41el\stanfit4anon_model_5944b02c79788fa0db5b3a93728ca2bf_4906440559444162650.cpp:800:
C:/ProgramData/Miniconda3/envs/pythonProject/Library/mingw-w64/include/c++/5.3.0/bits/unique_ptr.h:49:28: note: declared here
   template<typename> class auto_ptr;
                            ^
In file included from C:\Users\pytest\AppData\Local\Temp\pystan_wodq41el\stanfit4anon_model_5944b02c79788fa0db5b3a93728ca2bf_4906440559444162650.cpp:803:0:
C:\Users\pytest\AppData\Local\Temp\pystan_wodq41el\anon_model_5944b02c79788fa0db5b3a93728ca2bf.hpp: In member function 'void anon_model_5944b02c79788fa0db5b3a93728ca2bf_namespace::anon_model_5944b02c79788fa0db5b3a93728ca2bf::transform_inits(const stan::io::var_context&, std::vector<int>&, std::vector<double>&, std::ostream*) const':
C:\Users\pytest\AppData\Local\Temp\pystan_wodq41el\anon_model_5944b02c79788fa0db5b3a93728ca2bf.hpp:88:24: warning: typedef 'local_scalar_t__' locally defined but not used [-Wunused-local-typedefs]
         typedef double local_scalar_t__;
                        ^
C:\Users\pytest\AppData\Local\Temp\pystan_wodq41el\stanfit4anon_model_5944b02c79788fa0db5b3a93728ca2bf_4906440559444162650.cpp: In function 'PyObject* __pyx_pf_71stanfit4anon_model_5944b02c79788fa0db5b3a93728ca2bf_4906440559444162650_2_call_sampler(PyObject*, PyObject*, PyObject*, PyObject*)':
C:\Users\pytest\AppData\Local\Temp\pystan_wodq41el\stanfit4anon_model_5944b02c79788fa0db5b3a93728ca2bf_4906440559444162650.cpp:9572:30: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
     __pyx_t_12 = ((__pyx_t_9 != __pyx_v_fitptr->param_names_oi().size()) != 0);
                              ^
C:\Users\pytest\AppData\Local\Temp\pystan_wodq41el\stanfit4anon_model_5944b02c79788fa0db5b3a93728ca2bf_4906440559444162650.cpp: In function 'PyTypeObject* __Pyx_ImportType(PyObject*, const char*, const char*, size_t, __Pyx_ImportType_CheckSize)':
C:\Users\pytest\AppData\Local\Temp\pystan_wodq41el\stanfit4anon_model_5944b02c79788fa0db5b3a93728ca2bf_4906440559444162650.cpp:29274:53: warning: unknown conversion type character 'z' in format [-Wformat=]
             module_name, class_name, size, basicsize);
                                                     ^
C:\Users\pytest\AppData\Local\Temp\pystan_wodq41el\stanfit4anon_model_5944b02c79788fa0db5b3a93728ca2bf_4906440559444162650.cpp:29274:53: warning: unknown conversion type character 'z' in format [-Wformat=]
C:\Users\pytest\AppData\Local\Temp\pystan_wodq41el\stanfit4anon_model_5944b02c79788fa0db5b3a93728ca2bf_4906440559444162650.cpp:29274:53: warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]
writing c:\users\pytest\appdata\local\temp\pystan_wodq41el\stanfit4anon_model_5944b02c79788fa0db5b3a93728ca2bf_4906440559444162650.def
g++ -O -Wall -DMS_WIN64 -shared -s c:\users\pytest\appdata\local\temp\pystan_wodq41el\stanfit4anon_model_5944b02c79788fa0db5b3a93728ca2bf_4906440559444162650.o c:\users\pytest\appdata\local\temp\pystan_wodq41el\stanfit4anon_model_5944b02c79788fa0db5b3a93728ca2bf_4906440559444162650.def -LC:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\pythonProject\libs -LC:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\pythonProject -LC:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\pythonProject\PCbuild\amd64 -lpython37 -lucrt -lvcruntime140 -o C:\Users\pytest\AppData\Local\Temp\pystan_wodq41el\stanfit4anon_model_5944b02c79788fa0db5b3a93728ca2bf_4906440559444162650.pyd
C:/ProgramData/Miniconda3/envs/pythonProject/Library/mingw-w64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lucrt
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\pythonProject\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\unixccompiler.py", line 249, in link
    self.spawn(linker + ld_args)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\pythonProject\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\ccompiler.py", line 917, in spawn
    spawn(cmd, dry_run=self.dry_run, **kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\pythonProject\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\spawn.py", line 69, in spawn
    "command %r failed with exit code %s" % (cmd, exitcode))
distutils.errors.DistutilsExecError: command 'C:\\ProgramData\\Miniconda3\\envs\\pythonProject\\Library\\mingw-w64\\bin\\g++.exe' failed with exit code 1
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\pythonProject\lib\code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\pythonProject\lib\site-packages\pystan\model.py", line 378, in __init__
    build_extension.run()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\pythonProject\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 339, in run
    self.build_extensions()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\pythonProject\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 448, in build_extensions
    self._build_extensions_serial()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\pythonProject\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 473, in _build_extensions_serial
    self.build_extension(ext)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\pythonProject\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 559, in build_extension
    target_lang=language)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\pythonProject\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\ccompiler.py", line 717, in link_shared_object
    extra_preargs, extra_postargs, build_temp, target_lang)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\pythonProject\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cygwinccompiler.py", line 237, in link
    target_lang)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\pythonProject\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\unixccompiler.py", line 251, in link
    raise LinkError(msg)
distutils.errors.LinkError: command 'C:\\ProgramData\\Miniconda3\\envs\\pythonProject\\Library\\mingw-w64\\bin\\g++.exe' failed with exit code 1
```

How do I fix it?